# Does installing/updating 64-bit odbc driver automatically install/update 32-bit and 64-bit driver?

Tags: windows, odbc

I installed odbc driver 18 (64-bit), but notice that it shows up in both system32 and syswow64's odbc.exe.

Does installing/updating 64-bit odbc driver automatically install/update 32-bit and 64-bit driver?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but... You're not actually installing the 32-bit drivers. When you install the 64-bit ODBC, that includes the associated 32-bit thunks. Any call to a 32-bit ODBC control will get marshalled up to the 64-bit ODBC drivers and handled there. Windows has been doing that for efficiency ince the early days of 64-bit coding.